# Build with multiple ant tasks

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins build with three ant tasks.  If the first ant task fails, jenkins continues with the next ant task.  How can I get jenkins to fail the build and stop when an ant task fails?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're missing a "failonerror=true" attribute within your ant task.  A lot of sub tasks default this value to false.  (e.g. [Java Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) for example).

Could you post your entire ant script if that's not the case?